# Comparing PROLOG input to facts

Tags: prolog

Say I have a list of PROLOG facts, which are Blog Post titles, the author, and the year they were written:

```
blogpost('Title 1', 'author1' 2012).
blogpost('Title 2', 'author1', 2011). 
blogpost('Title 3', 'author1' 2010).
blogpost('Title 4', 'author1', 2006).
blogpost('Title 5', 'author2' 2009).
blogpost('Title 6', 'author2', 2011).
```

I want to write a rule which has two parameters/inputs, the author, and the year. If the author entered has written an article after the specified year, PROLOG would return `true`. 
Here is what I have tried:

```
authoredAfter(X,Z) :-
    blogpost(_,X,Z),
```

So if I queried `?- authoredAfter('author1',2010).` PROLOG would return `true` because the Author has written an article in 2010. However, if I query `?- authoredAfter('author1',2009).`, it would return `false`, but I want it to return `true` because author1 has written an article after that year.

My question is, how do I compare the user input value to the value in the fact?

Comment: Your database has some missing commas between the author and the year. Also, each clause should end with a dot, not with a comma.

Comment: Thanks for flagging that up, I wrote it into SO myself as the database for my program (University coursework) is *a lot* bigger and more complicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two use two distinct variables for the year of the article and for the year you want to start your search from and compare them. Something like this:

```
authoredAfter(Author, Year1):-
    blogpost(_, Author, Year2),
    Year2 >= Year1.
```

You express the fact that `Author` *authoredAfter* `Year1` if there is a blog post written by `Author` in `Year2` and `Year2 >= Year1`.

---

If you issue a query to see if *author1* wrote anything after 2009:

```
?- authoredAfter(author1, 2009).
true ;
true ;
true ;
false.
```

the goal is satisfied three times as author1 has 3 blog posts after 2009 (2010, 2011, 2012). If you want to get a single answer, no matter how many such articles exist, you can use `once/1`:

```
authoredAfter(Author, Year1):-
    once((blogpost(_, Author, Year2),
          Year2 >= Year1)).

?- authoredAfter(author1, 2009).
true.
```

Comment: this is perfect, thank you! Also thanks for the extra advice, I think I only need the single answer but it might come in handy later (this is University coursework!) :)