# Confusion over rule head and and rule body?

Tags: prolog, logic

**I am trying to write a rule from a given knowledge base about a local library that will allow me to see if two writers have written a text together.**

This is the knowledge base that is being used.

```
localLib(‘AHorowitz’, ‘Stolen Gods’, 2011, ‘Scorpia Rising’, 448, 4).
localLib(‘AHorowitz’, ‘Night Visitors’, 2000, ‘Stormbreaker’, 240, 2).
localLib(‘AHorowitz’, ‘Matador’, 2003, ‘Eagle Strike’, 340, 6).
localLib(‘AJohnston’, ‘Night Visitors’, 2000, ‘Stormbreaker’, 240, 2).
localLib(‘AJohnston’, ‘Matador’, 2003, ‘Eagle Strike’, 340, 6).
localLib(‘RMuchamore’, ‘Basic Training’, 2007, ‘The Recruit, 342, 3).
localLib(‘MHaddon’, ‘11.’, 2004, ‘The Curious Incident Of The Dog In The Night Time’, 226, 5).
```

The key for the KB is as follows:

```
localLib(w, e, y, t, n, c) where
w = writer’s name
e = excerpt in text
y = year of text
t = title of text
n = no. of pages in text 
c = no. of acknowledgements
```

This is the code I have written for the rule:

```
searchlocalLib(W,E,_,_,_,_):- localLib((W1,W2),E,_,_,_,_).
```

However I am getting extremely confused as this does not look right because I feel because I have not described W1 and W2 within the rule head the query will is therefore not working, please may I receive some guidance?

Also say I would also like to query ptolog if two writers have written together after a specified year e.g 2004. Do I just enter a year number into the rule above when corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the original rule.

```
searchlocalLib(W,E,_,_,_,_):- localLib((W1,W2),E,_,_,_,_).
```

It has two major problems. First, this rule assumes that if there are two authors of the same book, then the library entry (`localLib/6`) has a tuple with the authors as its first argument. This is not the case in your knowledge base where you use exactly one entry for each author of each book:

```
localLib(‘AHorowitz’, ‘Night Visitors’, 2000, ‘Stormbreaker’, 240, 2).
...
localLib(‘AJohnston’, ‘Night Visitors’, 2000, ‘Stormbreaker’, 240, 2).
```

Second, there are three singleton variables (`W`, `W1`, `W2`). Using this rule will not instantiate the variable `W`. The rule is missing some unification like `W = [W1, W2]` (ignoring the first problem).

---

You need to express in natural language what you will later represent in Prolog using a definite clause. Something like:

*Authors `W1` and `W2` wrote a book `T` together in year `Y` if there are two distinct library entries ...*

Then try to represent it as a rule in Prolog:

```
twoAuthors(T, [W1, W2], Y):-
    locallib(W1, T, Y, ...),
    locallib(W2, T, Y, ...),
    W1 \== W2.
```

---

For entries written after some specific year, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27783185/1478624) to a similar question.

Comment: Hey thanks for you help,I tried this method however when type the rule into the knowledge base it says there is ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal start of term.

Comment: It's not a full implementation. It's supposed to give you a hint about how to solve that.

Comment: Yes, I played around a bit and managed to get the answer. Thank you.